# Why is my jQuery .each iteration failing to use the attribute from each item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have some code that's finding the 'title' attribute from each child in a form.

It pulls out the title just correctly when I run 'console.log('title'). But when i try to apply the code to insert a label before the inner div of the fieldset, it just adds the same title ('About Me') to each of them.

html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset title="About Me">
        <!-- Going to convert legends to h4 // can choose the header style element? -->
        <div>
            <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset title="Radio Button Choice">
        <div>

            <label for="radio-choice-1">Choice 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" tabindex="2" value="choice-1" />

            <label for="radio-choice-2">Choice 2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-2" tabindex="3" value="choice-2" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="select-choice">Select Dropdown Choice:</label>
            <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice">
                <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
                <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
                <option value="Choice 3">Choice 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQ

```
kids = this.element.children('fieldset');
 kids.each(function(){ //function to do something to each of the child fieldset elements
 console.log(this);

 title = $(this).attr('title');

console.log(title); //this logs each title fine, or 'undefined' where there isn't one
$("<legend>" + title + "</legend>").insertBefore('div:first-child')
//that's where I'm just getting 'About me', on every damn one....
 });
```

Can anyone spot where I'm being a fool? Thanks.

Comment: Global variables are bad, use the `var` keyword when declaring your `title` variable inside the `.each()` function.

Comment: use prepend. that might work. I havent tested this but looks to me it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is too generic - `div:first-child` will select all of the divs.  Look for the div that is a descendant of `this` fieldset.

```
// Based on your existing code
$("<legend>" + title + "</legend>").insertBefore($(this).find('div:first-child'));

// Slightly cleaner
 $(this).prepend("<legend>" + title + "</legend>")
```

Also, make sure you make `title` a local variable with the `var` keyword:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
```

Comment: amazing. Thanks. So new to JS I get easily lost with how it does things. You've saved me some head banging

Comment: You've forgot about selecting first child of $(this) in `prepend` example.

Comment: @WTK You don't need to.  It is only necessary for `insertBefore`, but since I'm doing `prepend` it will attach it directly to the `fieldset`

Answer (score 2):

Dennis beat me to it, anyhow here's working example with slightly different approach to selecting first child http://jsfiddle.net/gMb8m/1/

The problem was that you were using wrong selector.

EDIT:
To address some of OP questions.

As to using `.children(0)` instead of `.find('div:first-child')` - I would have to check with jQuery source, but I imagine using the later may be slower since it using involves parsing selector while the `.children(0)` probably uses native DOM `.childNodes` internally. Passing a `0` to it just returns first child.

One situation in which using `.find('div:fist-child')` would be better if on some pages fieldset first child wouldn't be a `div` element and you would still want to insert legend before first div NOT before the first child. In that case using `.find` would return the first div.

As to why using prepend over insertBefore - they're both good (as you can tell from Dennis answer) and can be used in your situtation. It's just a matter of choice how you write your selectors. In this case I find my way cleaner.

P.S. In the example I've replaced your `kids` with my selector for fieldsets - don't mind that.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the jsfiddle too!

Comment: Quick question as to the whys: Why here (  $this.children(0).prepend('<legend>'+title+'</legend>'); ) is it children(0), also why prepend over insertBefore? tanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. Cheers :) Oh and one more thing always keep in mind that *caching* jQuery object in a variable instead of doing `$(this)` over and over again is considered good practice (plus it's good for performance).

Comment: The difference is that `prepend` adds the content at the beginning of the selected element and `insertBefore` adds the content to the selected elements' parent.

Comment: Yep, just a note that they can be used interchangeably (with proper syntax) as illustrated by my and Dennis example.

Comment: @WTK, how do you do that? (as I said I'm new to jQ)

Comment: They cannot be used interchangeably.  They do different things.  It looks visually similar in this case, but OP should read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com) for the details.

Comment: @Dennis I still say they can. In order to insert *something* before first child of *parent* you can do: `$(parent).prepend(something)` or `$(parent).children(0).insertBefore(something)`. Maybe I misunderstand "interchangeably" but you can use both to achive the same result.

Answer (score 1):

.prepend() seems to do what you're going for:

```
$('fieldset').each(function() {
    $(this).find('div:first-child').prepend('<legend>' + this.title + '</legend>');
});
```

Also, there's no need to promote a DOM object to a jQuery object as just to access a DOM attribute as in `$(this).attr('title')` :)

Comment: Would work except that `legend` element would be prepended to fieldset itself instead of first child of fieldset.

Comment: Ah, forgot that it was supposed to go in the div. Fixed

Comment: Not so clean anymore :( +1 for trying ;)